# Fazer SELECT entre duas tabelas no PHP

Tags: mysql

Atualmente estou utilizando a seguinte `query` para selecionar todas as postagens salvas no banco de dados: `"SELECT * FROM postagens ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 7"`, porém, quero selecionar apenas as postagens feitas pelos "amigos".

A relação de amizades está na tabela `amizades`, na qual quando são amigos, a coluna `status = 2`. Como relacionar ambas as tabelas para selecionar todas as postagens efetuadas pelos "amigos"?

O que consegui até o momento:

```
SELECT
   postagem.id, postagem.usuario, postagem.conteudo, postagem.data, postagem.hora,
   amizade.usuario1, amizade.usuario2, amizade.status
FROM
   postagens postagem
LEFT JOIN
   amizades amizade ON postagem.usuario = amizade.usuario2
WHERE
   amizade.status = 2
ORDER BY
   postagem.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Porém, quero selecionar todas as postagens feitas por mim e também por meus amigos (quando `amizade.status = 2`), e aí que estou falhando, não sei como selecionar apenas as minhas e as postagens dos meus amigos também, pois somente as minhas aparecem.

Colunas:

**postagens**:

```
id | usuario | conteudo | data | hora
```

**amizades**:

```
id | usuario1 | usuario2 | status
```

Comment: Acabei de ler a resposta do link, e entendi que terei que usar o INNER JOIN, porém não sei como adaptar ao meu caso, já que são casos diferentes. Poderia me dar um exemplo? @Bacco

Comment: @Bacco funcionou perfeitamente, meu erro estava em não usar o `OR` dentro do `ON` para comparar ambos os usuários, porém, há outro problema. Se não houver nenhuma amizade com `status = 2` nenhuma postagem é mostrada, e o correto seria mostrar as minhas postagens independente de ter algum amigo ou não. Como arrumar?

Comment: @Bacco caso queira dar uma olhada... 
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99611/problema-com-l%C3%B3gica-ao-usar-left-join/

Comment: Posta o script de criação das 2 tabelas.

Comment: Se você quer apenas os resultados que estão nas duas tabelas não use o LEFT JOIN use o INNER JOIN. O LEFT vai continuar trazendo todos os dados, mas no retorno da SQL os dados referentes a tabela amizade vão ser nulos quando for possível relacionar a postagem com a amizade, (mas mesmo assim trara as postagens).

Answer (score 1):

Segue o que você deseja

## Criação

```
create table postagens (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  usuario int,
  conteudo text);
  
create table amizades (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  usuario1 int,
  usuario2 int,
  status int);
  
insert into postagens (usuario, conteudo) values
(1, 'aksdjasdkasdj'),
(2, 'ja-s09920masd'),
(1, '90123091231092'),
(3, 'Nao devo ser exibidor');

insert into amizades (usuario1, usuario2, status) values
(1, 2, 2);
```

## Busca os dados

```
SELECT
        p.*,
        case when p.usuario = a.usuario1 then 'eu' else 'amigo' end as quem_enviou
FROM postagens p
INNER JOIN amizades a ON p.usuario = a.usuario1 OR p.usuario = a.usuario2
where (a.usuario1 = 1 or a.usuario2 = 1) and a.status = 2;
```

Onde está a.usuario1 = 1 or a.usuario2 = 1 coloque o ID do usuário que você quer buscar as mensagens.

Se quiser buscar apenas dos amigos, remova a parte do a.usuario1.
Se quiser buscar apenas as suas, remove a parte do a.usuario2.