# Problema com lógica ao usar LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, join

Em meu sistema, há um sistema de postagens e outro de amizades. Segue a estrutura das tabelas:

**postagens**: `id | usuario | conteudo | data | hora`

**amizades**: `id | usuario1 | usuario2 | status`

E estou utilizando a seguinte query para retornar as postagens tanto do usuário atual, como dos meus amigos (quando `status = 2`):

```
SELECT 
    postagem.id, usuario, conteudo, data, hora, usuario1, usuario2, status
FROM 
    postagens postagem
LEFT JOIN
    amizades ON usuario = usuario1 OR usuario = usuario2
WHERE
    status = 2 OR usuario = Igor
ORDER BY
    postagem.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Está funcionando perfeitamente, retornando tanto as minhas postagens (usuário logado), quanto as dos meus amigos (relação entre usuários onde `status = 2`), e aqui está um exemplo de dados contidos na tabela `amizades`:

```
2 | Igor  | Joao | 2
1 | Lucas | Igor | 0
```

Nos dados acima, quando `status = 2` significa que são amigos, e quando `status = 0` significa que não são amigos.

Porém, como há o meu usuário (Igor) nas duas linhas da tabela, ele duplica as postagens de tal usuário, ou seja, se houvesse outra linha na tabela, da qual faria a relação de amizade entre o meu usuário e outro qualquer, passaria a triplicar as postagens. Como resolver isso?

Comment: Você está passando o usuário por id?

Comment: @AndréBaill na realidade, ali onde está `usuario = Igor` é `usuario = '$usuario'`, eu apenas alterei para vocês poderem entender melhor meu problema.

Comment: Sim, mas é o id do usuario ou nome de usuario? teria que passar o id_usuario se não for

Comment: É o nome mesmo...

Comment: Tem que passar o Id para poder usar o left join corretamente.

Comment: SELECT * FROM postagens AS c1 LEFT JOIN amizades AS c2 USING(id_usuario)

Com isto, conseguimos relacionar e saber quais são as amizades que o usuario em questão possui

Comment: Mas pq não pode ser pelo nome? Esse nome de usuário seria como um id, é único

Comment: Porque cada vez que você for relacionar ou trocar o nome de usuario, ele não conseguirá autenticar, e também por segurança e ainda por questões justamente como esta que você postou, de relacionamento de tabelas :)

Comment: Não há como trocar o nome de usuário, após registrado, não pode ser alterado

Comment: beleza então...

Comment: De qualquer forma, como fazer? Eu tentei substituir o `ON` pelo `USING` assim como você disse, mas não funcionou... Você poderia dar um exemplo da query e como ela ficaria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tens aqui uma query que deve responder ao teu problema.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT postagem.id, 
        usuario, 
        conteudo, 
        data,
        hora
FROM postagens postagem
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT usuario1, usuario2
     FROM amizades
    WHERE status = 2
      AND ( usuario1 = 'Igor' or usuario2 = 'Igor')
) amizades
  ON amizades.usuario1 = postagem.usuario
  OR amizades.usuario2 = postagem.usuario
WHERE amizades.usuario1 IS NOT NULL
   OR postagem.usuario = 'Igor'
ORDER BY postagem.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Caso o anterior não funcione, faz desta maneira:

```
SELECT  postagem.id, 
        usuario, 
        conteudo, 
        dt
FROM postagens postagem
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT usuario1    id_amigo
     FROM amizades
    WHERE status = 2
      AND usuario2 = 'Igor'
    UNION
    SELECT usuario2
     FROM amizades 
    WHERE status = 2
      AND usuario1 = 'Igor'
) amizades
  ON amizades.id_amigo = postagem.usuario
WHERE amizades.id_amigo IS NOT NULL 
   OR postagem.usuario = 'Igor'
ORDER BY postagem.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Fica aqui o [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34113d/17)

Uma outra forma, conceptualmente mais simples de resolver o problema ainda que mais extensa, seria dividir os resultados em dois: Os teus posts e os posts dos teus amigos. Isso poderia ser feito assim

```
SELECT postagem.id, 
       usuario, 
       conteudo, 
       data, 
       hora, 
       'Minha postagem' AS Descricao
FROM postagens postagem
WHERE usuario = 'Igor'

UNION ALL

SELECT postagem.id,
       usuario, 
       conteudo, 
       data, 
       hora, 
       'Postagem de um amigo'
FROM postagens postagem
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT usuario1 id_amigo
    FROM   amizades
    WHERE status = 2
      AND usuario2 = 'Igor'

    UNION

    SELECT usuario2
    FROM   amizades
    WHERE status = 2
      AND usuario1 = 'Igor'

) amizades
   ON id_amigo = postagens.usuario
ORDER BY postagem.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Em relação às tuas questões:

- As descrições entre aspas são apenas um auxilio visual para perceber a origem das postagens. Pode ser removido da query.
- A ideia é combinar os teus posts com os posts dos teus amigos através do uso do UNION ALL - Combinar o resultado de duas queries
- Da forma como escreveste a tua query, não existe diferença entre o LEFT JOIN e o INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT 
    postagem.id, usuario, conteudo, data, hora, usuario1, usuario2, status
FROM 
    postagens postagem
LEFT JOIN
    amizades ON usuario = usuario1 OR usuario = usuario2
WHERE
status = 2   <- Esta condição obriga a que exista um registo na tabela amizades sendo desta forma equivalente ao INNER JOIN
```

Comment: Nossa, pensei que daria pra utilizar a query que eu estava tentando, por parecer mais simples... Mas ao ver a sua, me surgiram algumas dúvidas: Qual a função das descrições entre aspas (Minha postagem / Postagem de um amigo)? Tudo isso é uma query dividida em dois `SELECT's` dentro dela? Por que, no lugar de `LEFT JOIN` utilizar o `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Essa segunda solução realmente parece melhor, e funciona. Porém, se o usuário não possuir nenhuma amizade as suas próprias postagens não são mostradas

Comment: Continua não mostrando as próprias postagens se não há amigos :(

Comment: Ah sim, perfeito! Eu não havia notado a mudança do INNER para o LEFT, muito obrigado!

Comment: Acabei de verificar aqui, porém, agora ele continua duplicando. Se eu possuo, por exemplo, 1 amizade, ele não duplica como antes, mas, se eu tiver 2 amizades ele passa a duplicar... Lembrando que o usuário pode ser tanto usuario1 quanto usuario2, já que o usuário1 é quem manda o convite...

Comment: Podes usar o DISTINCT?

Comment: Desculpe, mas o que é isso?

Comment: Alterei novamente. Acrescentei um DISTINCT na primeira alternativa que deve remover os duplicados. Caso isso nao funcione, coloquei ainda uma outra alternativa.

Comment: Agora sim, perfeito!